# LaTeX in docker container using Alpine Linux (repository for Latex)

Tags: ubuntu, docker, latex, pdflatex, alpine-linux

I planning to use LaTeX in a docker environment for server-based generation of PDF-reports.

In the current test system environment I am playing around using [this docker container from the hub](https://hub.docker.com/r/narf/latex/) which seems to work quite well.

However, as stated the [container's dockerfile](https://github.com/natlownes/docker-latex/blob/master/Dockerfile) the container is based on Ubuntu which leads to a relative huge container size compared to the functionality I really need due to Ubuntu's system overhead.

I think I can get rid of that unneeded system overhead [as Docker Inc. did](https://www.brianchristner.io/docker-is-moving-to-alpine-linux/) by using [Alpine Linux](https://hub.docker.com/_/alpine/) instead of [Ubuntu](https://hub.docker.com/_/ubuntu/).

Unfortunately I cannot find any LaTeX packages in Alpine's repositories. I installed a non-docker based Alpine system as a virtual machine and tried:

```
apk update
apk search -v --description 'latex'
```

which did not found any related packages.
In addition to that I was not able to find any further information about LaTeX packages using Google.

So, is there something like an official repository providing LaTeX for Alpine or is there a way for using e.g. the Debian/Ubuntu packages in Alpine?

---

Update:

There is a [`texlive` package available](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/testing/x86_64/texlive). However as discussed [here](https://bugs.alpinelinux.org/issues/3920) that seems to be broken somehow...

---

Update due to broken link:

The link provided above is broken. The new link to the packages overview is [here](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=texlive&branch=&repo=&arch=&maintainer=).

Comment: I would love to have a smaller base image based on alpine...but I can't say I would know where to start to test whether it is functioning properly. LaTeX is awesome. Installing its dependencies is not so awesome...

Comment: Your link to the texlive package is broken.

Comment: The more I use LaTeX, the more I am surprised at how long it takes to build my own image. I don't fully know how the Ubuntu repositories work and how dependencies work...when I install textlive-full+texlive-math-extra, it seems like my image gets a lot larger. I mean by gigabytes. Given that the ubuntu base image is much smaller, and that a desktop install of ubuntu is gigabytes, it seems like somewhere LaTeX depends on a huge amount of packages. I can't fathom how something could depend on such a huge volume of packages without either never using some of them, or becoming unmanageable.

Comment: I probably didn't need textlive-full. That probably has a lot of contrib stuff. I guess if the alpine image started with getting the texlive-latex-base package working, things would be a hop, skip, and a jump from there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, the Ubuntu 14.04 container is only 65 MB. See https://hub.docker.com/r/library/ubuntu/tags/14.04/

So what makes the container large is texlive.
You would need to find a way to install only the parts of texlive you really need for your project.

Alpine provides now texlive in the Edge branch.
See https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=texlive*

You can read at https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Edge how to enable support for the Edge branch.

There is also one example of a Docker container based on Alpine linux, which might be worth to check out: https://github.com/mattmahn/docker-latex